# Things to consider when joining a company recently acquired by another company

Tags: interviewing, acquisition

What questions should I ask when interviewing for a company which was recently acquired by another company.

Also, what can be the pros and cons of working for such a company. Does it matter at all.

Comment: What will be your position in the company?

Comment: I will be a simple software developer, nothing more.

Comment: The acquisition was about 3 months back.

Answer (score 2):

Questions to ask:

- I see you were recently acquired by XYZ.  How do you see that change affecting this position?
- How long of an adjustment period do you believe there will be for this department as a result of the acquisition? (Reason being that some departments like HR, IT and Finance may have to change systems to all use the same stuff though other departments may not be quite as affected.)

Pros of working for such a company:

- Could be a way to have a big name on your resume if the new parent company has a good reputation.
- Could be dealing with lots of change and things being a bit chaotic if the new company is known for bringing in their systems to the company they just acquired.  This could be good or bad though I work in IT where change is common so I'd consider it a pro.

Cons of working for such a company:

- The plan you got hired under may go away if the managers in charge end up leaving which can happen in some acquisition cases.  If the managers go away then it may be that some new initiatives get scaled back or dropped.
- There may be some forms that have to handled twice.  The company may not have its benefits transfer until some time after the acquisition and so there may be some stuff to be done twice.

It doesn't necessarily matter but this depends a lot on the variables.  If the new parent company is known for buying companies but leaving everything alone, then not much would change in the company.  On the other hand, some companies will acquire others in order to take the assets which may be employees, intellectual property or other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I've been acquired twice, meaning that twice I was an employee of a small company that got acquired by a huge one (international, 50k+ employees).  The common theme of both experiences was: *change is inevitable and disruptive*.  Everything from how projects get planned to benefits to how you fill out your timesheet to whether IT blocks certain internet sites will change for you.

As someone coming into that situation, I would want to know what values the recently-acquired company holds most dearly -- what are the things they think are important to hang on to, and what are the things they're not going to worry about?  They will only be able to focus energy in a few areas; what's important enough to them?  Is it preserving a small-team agile culture?  Is it guarding the generous vacation/sick-leave policy?  Is it maintaining the current management structure?  Is it about keeping the balance of commercial and government-contract work the same as it is?  You can, meanwhile, do your own research on the acquiring company -- if they're big, then *somebody* is talking about them on GlassDoor or blogs or elsewhere.

As a practical matter, in any acquisition some of the acquirees get frustrated and leave -- maybe soon or maybe not for a while if there are retention bonuses, but there will be turnover, almost certainly more than the acquired company has previously experienced.  So you'll want to ask questions related to that -- how people are moved around on teams, how people stay up-to-date on projects other than their own (so they can move to other projects), whether promotions tend to be from within the company (versus new hires), and so on -- whatever issues are most important to you when entering a higher-turnover company.  How has the acquired company reacted to departures in the past, and how do they ramp up new people?  What are they doing to address employee concerns and mitigate departures?  (Conversely, questions about *why* people have left in the past are not going to be very helpful; they won't be good predictors.)

Interviewing candidates in the weeks following the two acquisitions I've lived through was difficult for me; I often just plain *couldn't* answer their questions about cultural changes, company direction, and bureaucracy, because I didn't know myself.  How the people you interview with react to your concerns -- on a scale from "rose-colored glasses" to "ack! the sky is falling!" -- 
will also tell you something about what it'll be like to work there during the transition.

Answer (score 1):

I've been in companies that were aquired and that did the aquiring and our clients get aquired all the time and since we usually also support the company that bought them, we see what happens with their sales staff. One of the key things I have noticed from various aquisitions is that it depends a lot on whether they are buying the company to get some sort of new type of work (where they need the employees) or if they do the same type of work already and are buying the company to get their customers (where they could care less about the employees). In the second case, your job at the bought company will almost certainly disappear in a year or less.

Also certain functions like senior management and shared functions like HR and Finance will likely be merged and the buying company employees are usually but not always the ones who keep their jobs.

There is opportunity in converting systems though if you are someone who has the skill set and past experience to do the data conversions.

Since you would be fairly new, you won't have anyone in the org that hired you who will know your work well enough to be your supporter in determining which people will be laid off if they have a lay-off fairly quickly. So your political postion would be precarious. On the other hand, the new company might see you as someone who is not entrenched in the old way and thus more likely to adjust. Your best bet if you take the job is to start making contacts with people in the company doing the buying.

Another thing to consider is to get any employment conditions in writing. The benefits still may change, but if you have an unofficial arrangement for extra time off with the manager or something else, be aware that he might not be there when you want to take the time off or unofficial benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Topics to at least inquire about:

- **Location**: One thing that can happen is that the company wants to consolidate the amount of office space. So be concerned that the project may be moved to another building, city or state.
- **Benefits**: Don't fall in love with a specific benefit. The parent company may want to switch the employes another health care insurer, they may change the amount of vacation, or the matching rules for the 401K. Generally these don't happen until the next year, but they are always a concern to the employees being acquired. They can also change rules regarding working from home, and flexible work hours.
- **Consolidation of functions**. This generally impacts overhead positions. Instead of two company websites to maintain there is now only one. This can impact offices that support contracting, purchasing, travel, payroll...

Of course these changes could happen even if the company isn't being bought, but the change in management does generally lead to a review of costs and benefits.

Answer (score 0):

The main Qs you need to ask is

1 Is there anyone in the acquiring company doing the role I have been hired for
2 Is the merger process complete ie have they gone through any downsizing /closing offices as a result of duplication and overlap.

And about T&C’s post merger some counties have laws to protect your T&C on transfer  EU states have TUPE which varies from country to country – for example The UK has average protection Spain very much less so.

The main con is

Your job is probably more precarious especially if you are in a probationary period if they are making people redundant your probably going to be first on the list so have a  plan B prepared